# Definition of term-wise split exact sequences of complexes

Tags: homological-algebra, triangulated-categories, derived-categories

In Stacks, [Section 13.9](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014D), one can find the definition of term-wise split exact sequences of complexes: we say that the exact sequence of complexes
$ 0 \rightarrow A^\bullet \rightarrow B^\bullet \rightarrow C^\bullet \rightarrow 0 $ is term-wise split if $ B^\bullet = A^\bullet \oplus C^\bullet $ in a way that is compatible with the morphisms $ A^\bullet \rightarrow B^\bullet $ and $ B^\bullet \rightarrow C^\bullet $.

I understood it as saying that the complex $ 0 \rightarrow A^\bullet \rightarrow B^\bullet \rightarrow C^\bullet \rightarrow 0 $  is isomorphic (in $ \mathrm{Kom}(A) $) to $ 0 \rightarrow A^\bullet \rightarrow A^\bullet \oplus C^\bullet \rightarrow C^\bullet \rightarrow 0 $. However, it seems to me that this wouldn't be the case, since afterwards the connection morphism $ C^\bullet \overset\delta\rightarrow A[1]^\bullet $ is defined as the composite $$ C^\bullet \rightarrow A^\bullet \oplus C^\bullet \overset{d}\rightarrow A[1]^\bullet \oplus C[1]^\bullet \rightarrow A[1]^\bullet $$
But wouldn't that composite vanish given that $ d $ is just $ d_A \oplus d_B $?

What is actually meant by compatibility with those morphisms?

Comment: A term-wise split exact sequence is a a sequence $0\to A^\bullet\to B^\bullet\to C^\bullet\to 0$ such that for all $n$, the sequence $0\to A^n\to B^n\to C^n\to 0$ splits. So I think you misunderstood what the stack project said and what you wrote is not correct. The point is that, you need to forget the differentials in the complexes $A^\bullet, B^\bullet, C^\bullet$.

Comment: My bad, the definition is actually pretty clear, they use $ \alpha^n $ and $ \beta^n $…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of termwise split is merely that for each $n$, the short exact sequence $0\to A^n\to B^n\to C^n\to 0$ splits.  This gives an isomorphism $B^n\cong A^n\oplus C^n$, but crucially, this splitting is not assumed to be compatible with the differentials in the chain complex.  So, for instance, for each $n$ we have a map $C^n\to B^n$ which splits the surjection $B^n\to C^n$, but these maps $C^n\to B^n$ may not form a morphism of chain complexes $C^\bullet\to B^\bullet$.  As a result, $B^\bullet$ is not necessarily isomorphic to $A^\bullet\oplus C^\bullet$ as a chain complex; we only have objectwise isomorphisms $B^n\to A^n\oplus C^n$ which may not commute with the differentials.